# How can I group files by task in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I frequently work with logical groupings of files in JetBrains WebStorm, and I'm looking for a way to close/reopen those same files quickly, and ideally with names and descriptions. For instance, if I need to work on the login page, including .js, .html, .css, etc. files, having a menu of task-named file groupings that I can refer to with a keystroke would be very handy.

Does anyone know of a built-in way or a plugin to accomplish this? Having to use ctrl-e and hunt through my open file history is tedious.

**Note:** I am not looking to group files by dot extension in the project explorer as Visual Studio does.

Answer (score 0):

LazyOne's duplicate reference yielded some information that led me to an answer. It turns out the functionality I want is wrapped inside the "Tasks and Contexts" tool. This allows you to swap IDE states based on a named task, including which files you have open, and, I presume, other parts of the IDE. This is well-integrated into the UI, having a drop-down with task names in the tool bar.

This can also be integrated with issue tracking systems, but since I'm being forced to use TFS (ick), this is irrelevant to me. I'm much more concerned with logical- over issue-grouping.

Here's some good documentation on the feature:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/opening-and-creating-tasks.html